# Ajax issue of Django user login using bootstrap 3.x modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

My purpose is once modal form submitted, ajax pass the username and password to a view and get back the json info to update the modal form, I trace the djanog code ,and 100% sure the JsonResponse(rsdic) has been executed in server side, as well as client fully receive the son info with ajax success function.

The problem is how to update the **#error_message1** field which embeded in model. I tried .html() or .append(), all failed.

I leave the core coding for your reference, many thanks again for your help again.

**ajax component:**

```html
$.ajax(
    {
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: {
              'username': username,
              'password': password
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
              $('#login-form')[0].reset();
                  if (data.ret != '1107'){
                    var htmlcode ="<p> data.info </p>";
                    $('#modal').find('.error_message1').append(htmlcode);
                }
            },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                 },
     });
```

**html component:**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">  
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="form-modal-body" class="modal-body">  
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times</button>
                  <h4>EXP LOGIN</h4>
                <form role="form" action="{% url 'auth_login' %}" method="post" id="login-form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <ul>
                       <li>
                         <div class="g-icon"><i class="iconfont icon-yonghu"></i></div>
                         <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="User name" />
                       </li>
                      <li>
                         <div class="g-icon"><i class="iconfont icon-mima"></i></div>
                         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" onblur="check1()" />
                         <div class="g-cue" id="error_message1">Your email or password was entered incorrectly.</div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="g-btn">
                      <input class="g-submit" id='login-button' type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                    </div>
                    <p><span>{% trans "Not a member?" %} <a href="{% url 'registration_register' %}">Join now.</a></span></p>

               </form>
            </div>  
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `error_message1` as **id** not **class**

```
$('#modal').find('#error_message1').html(htmlcode);
```

Comment: Too simple to find it. Many thanks, Satendra!! You save my life now!